# Access denied to site collection administrator

Tags: 2013, permissions, site-collection, central-administration

I am facing a very strange issue.

I have two web applications. Inside those applications are two site collections each. When I log in as site collection administrator I can access all three site collections except one. When I try to access that particular site in browser I get message:

> Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

This user is added in Site Collection Administrator section of all 4 sites but only 1 site has problem.

I have even added site collection admin in User Policy in CA and gave FULL RIGHTS and FULL READ permissions.

Did iisreset, restart SQL server and SharePoint timer server but no luck. How do I solve this issue?

**EDIT**

User NT AUTHORITY was missing from user policy of problematic web application (not that it should have any effect because other site collection are working fine in this web application) but still I added this user and noticed that:

In problematic web application it appears as
i:0#.w|NT AUTHORITY

While in other web application it appears as
NT AUTHORITY

Comment: Had the same problem a year ago or so. You might find something useful here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105864/site-collection-administrators-permissions-missing

Comment: I tried some solutions mentioned in that post but none of them worked.

Comment: did you tried to access the page other than home page of that problematic site? try "/Problematic Site/__layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" or "settings.aspx". and check it happens with all pages within site or not?

Comment: All pages are inaccessible by all users including farm admin and site collection admin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied unique permissions for the 4th site by any chance ? That might be the case

Comment: May be but why site collection administrator and farm admin are unable to access the site?

Comment: I think the following thread might help you with that.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/933d18d8-8d61-448e-95a0-363d71dced73/sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: I have already tried solution provided in that link but it didn't work. Looks like the only way to fix is to delete web application and create again and then attached existing content database.

Comment: Yeah i suppose so, i never experienced this problem. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem is fixed.

1. Took backup of content database
2. Deleted the web application but didn't delete content database
3. Created a new web application using existing content database.

Everything is working.

Comment: ah a. Well done Frank